# Use spatialite extension for SQLite on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, spatialite

I know that this has been asked in some similar ways before. However, all questions I found on this dealt with some very specific system setups which were not applicable for me (because so is mine).

System:

- Windows 7 64bit
- Python 3.4 64bit
- sqlite3 2.6.0 (shipped with Python I guess)
- Spatialite Windows binaries 2.3.1
  (anything else of importance?)

How can I activate the `spatialite` extension for the ´sqlite3´ module?

What I tried (the way that other people in similar questions say it works):

- Downloading from https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.1/binaries.html :

  - libspatialite-win-x86-2.3.1.zip
  - proj-win-x86-4.6.1.zip
  - geos-win-x86-3.1.1.zip
  - libiconv-win-x86-1.9.2.zip
- unzipping all of them into the same folder on C:\
- (also tried only putting the DLLs into that folder)
- putting that folder into my system PATH variable

Then, running

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.execute('SELECT load_extension("libspatialite-2.dll")')
```

gives

```
conn.execute("SELECT load_extension('libspatialite-2.dll')")
sqlite3.OperationalError: The specified module could not be found.
```

What more can I try to make this work?

Comment: As a suggestion, put Spatialite folder as first in your PATH environment variable. I was having troubles because Spatialite path was after GDAL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you probably don't have the folder in which libspatialite-2.dll is placed in your PATH.
Perhaps you can add the folder from within your Python script (I don't know any Python).
Or else you could add it from the Windows properties interface.

BTW you are using a very old version of spatialite: have a look here for newer versions:
https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index

Comment: The old version of spatialite was the issue! Google confused me with subpages of old spatialite versions on [https://www.gaia-gis.it](https://www.gaia-gis.it) when searching for Windows binaries, that's why I thought there were no more recent ones. Besides, the library/binaries have been renamed from `spatialite-2(/3/4).dll` to `mod_spatialite.dll` which made me think that this is something different. Downloading `mod_spatialite-4.2.0-win-amd64.7z` from [this download page](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64/) and putting all DLLs into `c:\Windows\system32` solved the issue.

Comment: By the way, [this download page on Gaia GIS](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-x86/) provides Windows 32bit binaries.
I lost almost a whole workday by trying to compile mod_spatialite myself (don't do this on Windows :-( ) before I finally found the compiled binaries -_-

Comment: As a suggestion, put Spatialite folder as first in your PATH environment variable. I was having troubles because Spatialite path was after GDAL.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently faced this problem with `mod_spatialite.dll` with Spatialite 5.0.1, Python 3.8 (with Anaconda) and Windows 10. I fixed the problem with the following steps:

1. Installed OSGeo4W;
2. Copied all the files and folders in `OSGeo4W64\bin` to `anaconda3\Library\bin` (**without** replacing the existing files, as this may break other things in the Python installation). I backed up this folder beforehand so I could undo everything, just in case things go wrong;
3. Copied `mod_spatialite.dll` (which I had already downloaded) into `anaconda3\Library\bin`.

The reason why I think I had this problem is because of missing recursive dll dependencies; since just getting the direct dependencies (through `dumpbin /dependents mod_spatialite.dll`) and copying them to the `anaconda3\Library\bin` folder did not solve the problem, so I came to the conclusion that I was missing a dependency of some dependency. Given that all dependencies are already neatly placed in `OSGeo4W64\bin`, copying everything from there solved it for me.