# Where does the Qt sqlite plugin look for extension libraries

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt5

I have made the appropriate modification as found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427868/could-not-load-spatialite-extension-in-qsqlite-qt-5-9) to enable the Qt sqlite plugin to load extensions. However, when I run `SELECT load_extension('spatialite_mod')`, I now get the error `The specified module could not be found`

On a Windows Qt installation, where do I need to put the `spatialite_mod.dll` file so that it can be found a runtime? I have already tried putting it in the binary directory without any success.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a multi-part problem.

The answer to the original question is that Qt looks for the libraries in the working directory (`QDir::currentPath()`) and in the Windows PATH.

**Part 1:**

On Windows, the `specified module could not be found` error also can mean that one of mod_spatialite.dll dependencies was not found. In my case, I had forgotten to move these dependencies to the same directory as mod_spatialite.dll. They include:

- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- libsqlite3-0.dll
- libxml2-2.dll
- zlib1.dll
- libfreexl-1.dll
- libgeos_c-1.dll
- libgeos-3-5-0.dll
- libiconv-2.dll
- liblzma-5.cll
- libproj-9.dll

**Part 2:**

The `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` and `libstdc++-6.dll` libraries shipped with libspatialite do not work with Windows 10. Read more about this [here](http://blog.jrg.com.br/2016/04/25/Fixing-spatialite-loading-problem/) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/u2QZpQL_6ek). They would crash the program when loaded. The fix for me was to grab the same libraries from my Qt installation at C:\Qt\5.11.3\mingw53_32.